# Call method from apex class generated from wsdl file

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex

I don't know how to call method from wsdl file apex class.[This is wsdl file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f606a55b3143d6d1024b) Anyone please help me for this.Now i want call "ConvertHistoricalValue" method for get response. How can i call it?

```
wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap testCls = new wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap();

wwwXigniteComServices.Header h = new wwwXigniteComServices.Header();

h.Username='****';
h.Password='****';
h.Tracer='****';
testCls.Header = h

testCls.GetRealTimeRate('EURUSD');
```

When i'm trying to call "XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap" this method, it shows some error.

The error looks like"System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element Outcome"

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share you generated Apex wsdl files..?

Comment: Sorry sir, i don't know How can i share my apex class file? it contains 1500 lines of code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58a1fced97f136b27254

Comment: How can i call some method from this class and get response

Comment: wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap testCls = new wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap();
wwwXigniteComServices.Header h = new wwwXigniteComServices.Header();
h.Username='****';
h.Password='****';
h.Tracer='****';
testCls.Header = h;
testCls.GetRealTimeRate('EURUSD');

Comment: When i'm trying to call "XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap" this method its show some error

Comment: Line: 1359, Column: 1
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element Outcome

Comment: How can i solve it, Any suggestion available for this.

Comment: I had a quick look at the [WSDL](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f606a55b3143d6d1024b). Have you been updating the WSDL by hand? I see commented out wsdl:port elements. Any other changes?

Answer (score 1):

I pulled down what I think is the the original WSDL from http://globalcurrencies.xignite.com/xGlobalCurrencies.asmx?wsdl and ran it through the custom version of Wsdl2Apex in the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) tool. (Disclosure: This is a free tool from my current employer)

I opted to only generate the Apex method for GetRealTimeRate web method. You can get the generated [wwwXigniteComServices](https://gist.github.com/FishOfPrey/277ee04fafedf36f3543) class.

After adding the Remote Site setting I used a Trail account with the following anonymous Apex code:

```
wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap testCls = new wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap();

wwwXigniteComServices.Header h = new wwwXigniteComServices.Header();
h.Username='daniel.ballinger@example.com';
h.Password='notMyRealPassword';
h.Tracer='51ED22B1IAMWEASELF1CFF9650B4'; //Found value in API Tokens on xignite website
testCls.Header = h;

wwwXigniteComServices.Rate eurUsdRate = testCls.GetRealTimeRate('EURUSD');
System.debug(eurUsdRate);
```

That came back without a parsing error, although I did hit the unregistered requests limit, so can't show  any meaningful output.

Comment: Sir, my response is in array, Now, i want to split it or parse this response..?

Comment: Could u pls help me

Comment: @JanaShree I don't see any response data in the `Rate` class that would be an array. There is documentation on how to work with [Arrays and Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex4_3.htm). They are interchangeable in apex. Other than that, Maybe ask a new question about the specific problem you are having.